# Create folder under WEB-INF in Web Application

Tags: java, web-inf

What is the correct way to create a folder under MyProject/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/myfolder dynamically?

I have been trying to use:

```
@Autowired ServletContext sc;
...
String path = sc.getRealPath("WEB-INF");
File file = new File(path + "/myfolder);
if(!file.exists()) file.mkdirs();
```

I have the problem with the above snippet code is that the folder is not created correctly in MyProjet folder but in .metadata/MyProject/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/.

How can I create a folder under WEB-INF (not under .metadata) correctly and dynamically?

Comment: Consider a war file as a read-only executable. Just like an executable file or a DLL. You shouldn't try to store anything in the war at runtime. Store it elsewhere: in the database, on the file system, whatever.

Comment: Please remove the tag spring-mvc since its not related

Comment: Create the folder ahead of time IF you REALLY need it. Why does it have to be dynamically created?